# upgrade to php 8.* version on centos 7.9

Tags: centos, upgrade, php, cpanel

I have a Centos 7.9 with PHP 7.4.33 pre installed. followed this command steps for upgrading the php version to 8.1:

```
sudo yum install -y https://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
sudo yum install -y yum-utils
sudo yum-config-manager --enable remi-php81
sudo yum-config-manager --disable remi-php74
sudo yum install -y php php-common php-opcache php-mcrypt php-cli php-gd php-curl php-mysqlnd
```

but at the end it returns:

```
No package php available.
No package php-common available.
No package php-opcache available.
No package php-mcrypt available.
No package php-cli available.
No package php-gd available.
No package php-curl available.
No package php-mysqlnd available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

retried with this:

```
yum --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo="remi-php81" list available
```

got same return. also tried:

```
sudo yum clean all
sudo yum update
```

and:

```
sudo yum install -y php81 php81-common php81-opcache php81-cli php81-gd php81-curl php81-mysqlnd
```

Same... .

what should i do?

---

Update:
I have a Cpanel WHM on this server. in php version manager, i was able to change the version to 8. But what I want is 8.1 and it is not among the options.

Comment: Check "exclude" directive in yum configuration. Also note that centos 7 is old, terribly old, and close to its end of life in a few months.

Answer (score 0):

You should update the packages, not install them:

```
yum update php\*
```

Comment: If a package is already installed when you run `yum install` you should get a message  `Package foo-1.2.3 is already installed.` `No package` indicates that there is another problem.

Comment: @doneal24, correct. But seems like (for me) the OP try to install packages which do not exist (in repo)

Comment: tried that, there is no update!